# Deploying ASP.NET 4.0 website on IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've deployed ASP.net site on IIS and crashing into an null reference exception. It runs fine ASP.net development server but fails to load on the IIS.

I have tried reinstalling the IIS and even aspnet_regiis as well. But the error remains. Please find the error below.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +183
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean  includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3047
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: Problem may be in page_load event of your default.aspx, are checking for any session value and could you post code for page load from default.aspx

Comment: do you have any starting page set?

Comment: Can you post the code of the page throwing error? The reason this error is thrown is when you use non-initialized objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how it worked but I just added the website as an application under Default Website and now its working.No errors now. Earlier I was adding this as an independent website.. Does anyone has an explanatio n for this>>?

Answer (score 1):

Any objects that u may use in yr page load event, make sure u check if they are not null

```
if (myObject != null)
{
   // do what u need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it, you should add your website under the default website, or you set in the IIS to start from your website.

Comment: Any explanation why it happens like that??

Comment: Er, It's hard to know the real problem based on the implicit description. If you add a web project under the default website, it is seen as an application of the default website, and you can visit it by localhost. However, if you want to deploy it as an independent website, you should right click and "add website", and configure the website,then add your project as an application. I think the reason is you can deploy website though IIS, but a web project can't be deployed directly, it should be deployed as an application, and a website can have many applications.